# selected value in dropdownlist is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to display a complex viewmodel in a view, everything works fine except one dropdownlist. I am displaying a list of enum, and set the selected object as it should be. But for an unknown reason, its not showing the selected value. I have tried many times with but failed -- please help me. The code is given below -

Enum:

```
public enum CommentStatus
{
    NoStatus = 0,
    Resolved = 1,
    NotApplicable = 2
}
```

Model:

```
public class CheckComments
{
    public string EntryId { get; set; }
    public int Serial { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
    public CommentStatus CommentStatus { get; set; } 
}

public class CheckDataViewModel
{
  public string EntryId { get; set; }
  public string CheckId { get; set; }
  public decimal Value { get; set; }
  public List<CheckComments> CheckCommentsList { get; set; } 

  public List<string> CommentStatusList { get; set; } 
}
```

Controller:

```
public class CheckDataController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult GetEnteredCheckData(string entryId)
   {
      var checkDataViewModel = new CheckDataViewModel();
      var checkData = new CheckDataManager().GetCheckData(entryId);

      checkDataViewModel.EntryId = checkData.EntryId;
      checkDataViewModel.CheckId = checkData.CheckId;
      checkDataViewModel.Value = checkData.Value;
      checkDataViewModel.CheckCommentsList = checkData.Comments;
      checkDataViewModel.CommentStatusList = Enum.GetNames(typeof (CommentStatus)).ToList();

            return View("EnteredCheckData", checkDataViewModel);
   }
}
```

View:

```
@model PDCA.Web.Models.CheckDataViewModel
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "EnteredCheckData";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
   <fieldset>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="span3">
            <div class="text-left">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EntryId)</div>
         </div>
         <div class="span3">
            <div class="text-left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EntryId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EntryId)
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Check Information</legend>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="span3">
            <div class="text-left">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CheckId)</div>
         </div>
         <div class="span3">
            <div class="text-left">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Check.CheckId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Check.CheckId)
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
       <legend>Comments</legend>

       <div>
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Serial
                </th>
                <th>
                    Comment
                </th>
                <th>
                    Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
            </tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CheckCommentsList.Count; i++)
            {
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].Serial)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].Serial)
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].Comment)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].Comment)
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].CommentDate)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].CommentDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].CommentStatus, new SelectList(Model.CommentStatusList, Model.CheckCommentsList[i].CommentStatus))
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].CommentStatus)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Update Status", "UpdateCommentStatus", new { Model.EntryId, Model.CheckCommentsList[i].Serial, Model.Check.CheckTitle, Model.Check.CheckId })|
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteComment", new { Model.CheckCommentsList[i].Serial, Model.EntryId })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
         </table>
     </div>

  </fieldset>
}
<div>
   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

The code is too lengthy but I think this will help you to understand my mistakes. Thanks in advance friends.

Comment: I have found the solution. A simple ToString() in selected object has completed it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

> @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].CommentStatus, new SelectList(Model.CommentStatusList, Model.CheckCommentsList[i].CommentStatus.ToString()))